# PHP Get min value from array and associated row data?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with the following data, I am trying to find the column with the lowest price and then get the associated row data (stock and supplier) value, I have managed to get the lowest price but am not sure how to get the associated row data for stock and supplier, any adivce. Thanks

```
$productdata=array
(
    array('Price'=>$row['price1'],'Stock'=>$row['stock1'],'Supplier'=>$row['supplier1']),
    array('Price'=>$row['price2'],'Stock'=>$row['stock2'],'Supplier'=>$row['supplier2']),
    array('Price'=>$row['price3'],'Stock'=>$row['stock3'],'Supplier'=>$row['supplier3'])
    );
$filtered_array = array_filter($productdata, function($v) {
return $v['Price'];});

$minprice= min( array_column( $filtered_array, 'Price') );
 print_r($minprice);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A solution without using sorting or loops:**

Get all the prices in an array, then get the key of the lowest price

```
$prices = array_column($productdata, 'Price');
$min_price = min($prices);
$key = array_search($min_price, $prices);
```

Output the matching row:

```
$match = $productdata[$key];
echo '<pre>' . print_r($match, true) . '</pre>';
```

**Documentation:**

- [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
- [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)
- [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 1):

First sort your array in ascending order then you will get first element as lowest.

```
$filtered_array=array
(
    array('Price'=>100,'Stock'=>1000,'Supplier'=>'Kapil'),
    array('Price'=>50,'Stock'=>500,'Supplier'=>'Kapil2'),
    array('Price'=>200,'Stock'=>2000,'Supplier'=>'Kapil3')
    );

 for($i = 0; $i < count($filtered_array); $i++ ) {
    for($j = $i+1; $j< count($filtered_array); $j++ ) {

        if($filtered_array[$i]['Price'] > $filtered_array[$j]['Price']) {
            $temp = $filtered_array[$j];
            $filtered_array[$j] = $filtered_array[$i];
            $filtered_array[$i] = $temp;
        }
    }
 }
 print_r($filtered_array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array by price in ascending order using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). The array with to lowest price will then be the first item `$productdata[0]`

```
usort($productdata, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['Price'] > $b['Price'];
});

echo $productdata[0]["Stock"];
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/trgdC)